# What are the benefits of using lazy initialization when i.e. calling Doctrine's EntityManager?

Tags: php, lazy-initialization, doctrine

**TL;DR:** I have noted that [some tutorials](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#entity-repositories) are using an extra method call to retrieve a variable, in my case `EntityManager` of Doctrine.  Is it generally a good idea to use such extra method call, when it seemingly adds overhead, even if this overhead is "just a little bit" of overhead?  In my case I am talking about the code that uses `$this->getEntityManager()` and does not use `$this->entityManager` directly

Instantiation of `EntityManager` in Doctrine is an expensive procedure.  There are some (rare) times where I do not need an `EntityManager` to do something although *most* of the times I do.

I have noticed that many tutorials use an "extra" method to retrieve `EntityManager`, like so (see `getEntityManager`):

```
class GenericRepository
{

    /**
     *
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     *
     * @return EntityManager
     */
    final public function getEntityManager()
    {
        if ($this->em === null)
            $this->em = DoctrineConnector::getEntityManager();

        return $this->em;
    }
}
```

and later in my code I have something like this:

```
class CustomRepository extends GenericRepository
{

    /**
     * Looks up Category Entity by its string name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Product
     */
    function getProduct($partNumber)
    {
        $product = $this->getEntityManager() //<--calling entity Manager indirectly
        ->getRepository(ProductEntity::class)
        ->findOneBy(array(
            'model' => $partNumber
        ));

        return $product;
    }
}
```

**Question**

I can replace `getEntityManager()` call above with `em`, if in my `GenericRepository` class I initialize the repository right away at construction time.  I can then shorten my code to be like below and avoid an extra `getEntityManager()` method call, like so:

```
        $product = $this->em  //<-- this is different, using em directly
        ->getRepository(ProductEntity::class)
        ->findOneBy(array(
            'model' => $partNumber
        ));
```

`em` will be guaranteed to be non-null in that case if I initialize it at construction time.

Why not instead refer to the `$em` directly and remove lazy initialization?

What would be some reasons to keep `getEntityManager()` in my code and to keep using lazy initialization at the expense of the overhead of an extra method call?

Comment: This is a request for a list

Answer (score 1):

If you use lazy instantiation, and a previous transaction resulted an exception and rollback, then the reference you're keeping to the EntityManager will point to an EntityManager in the closed state. Any query will fail. The reason to get the EM from Doctrine every time is that it will give you a new instance of an EM if the previous EM was closed due to a rollback.

At least, that's the behavior from Symfony2+ IIRC. I don't believe that's specific to symfony but it might be.